# Sonar Qube code analysis failed with exist code 1

Tags: sonarqube

I am using sonar `qube` for code analyzer but getting error as below:

```
Preparing `SonarQube` scanner...
`realpath`: '': No such file or directory
ERROR in /opt/resource/out : line 85 with exit code 1
```

and not getting specific reason why it is failing.

Comment: What is the command you used to scan code?

Comment: Running it through CI pipelines jobs

Comment: You haven't shown us any details that we could use to diagnose what you did wrong. Show us exactly what you did.

Comment: Follow this link will help to understand more.
https://github.com/cathive/concourse-sonarqube-resource/issues/66

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some input in your configuration, most likely something with maven (default settings.xml pointing to wrong repo). Default maven install folder for [concourse-sonarqube-resource](https://github.com/cathive/concourse-sonarqube-resource) is */opt/apache-maven*. By using the [**debug**](https://github.com/cathive/concourse-sonarqube-resource) flag, whole trace (*mvn -X*) will be shown and you get your specific reason.

```
type: sonar-runner
source:
  host_url: ((sonarqube.url))
  __debug: true
```